# Regex to match part of a hex

Tags: regex

so I need to use regex to match a part of a hexadecimal string, but that part is random. Let me try to explain more:

So I have this hexa data:

```
70 75 62 71 00 7e 00 01 4c 00 06 72 61 6e 64 6f 6d 74 00 1c 4c 6a 2f 73 2f 6e 64 6f 6d 3b 78 70 77 25 00 00 00 20 f2 90 c2 91 c4 c4 ca 91 c0 c0 ca 91 94 cb c5 97 90 c5 90 c2 90 96 c7 ca 91 91 93 94 c6 c5 c6 cb c0 78
```

I need to match only the f2 in that case. But that is not always the case. Each data will be different. The only thing that is always the same is the '00 00 00' part and the '78' at the end. All the rest is random.

I managed to make the following regex:
/(?=00 00 00).+?(?=78)/
The output is:

```
00 00 00 20 f2 90 c2 91 c4 c4 ca 91 c0 c0 ca 91 94 cb c5 97 90 c5 90 c2 90 96 c7 ca 91 91 93 94 c6 c5 c6 cb c0
```

But I dont know how to build a regex to take only the 'f2' (reminder: not always is going to be f2)

Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly do you want for input/output?  The 2nd byte after three zero bytes on a line ending in 78?

Comment: I don't get you. If you are interested only in `f2`, why do you need a regex? Use a function that checks if `f2` is present in the string and that's all.

Comment: @MarkTolonen That is exactly what I want, I need to check the second byte after que three zero (00 00 00 xx ??), where xx is irrelevant and the ?? is the byte that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the explanation in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75315320/regex-to-match-part-of-a-hex/75316350#comment132897348_75315320), the regex that you need is:

```
(?<=00 00 00 [0-9a-f]{2} )[0-9a-f]{2}
```

Providing the first input string from the question, this regex matches `f2` (no spaces around it).
Check it [online](https://regex101.com/r/KW3CpO/1).

How it works:

```
(?<=                 # start of a positive lookbehind
  00 00 00           # match the exact string ("00 00 00 ")
  [0-9a-f]           # match one hex digit (lowercase only)
  {2}                # match the previous twice (i.e. two hex digits)
                     # there is a space after ")"
)                    # end of the lookbehind
[0-9a-f]{2}          # match two hex digits
```

The positive lookbehind works like a non-capturing group but it is not part of the match. Basically it says that the matching part (`[0-9a-f]{2}`) matches only if it is preceded by a match of the lookbehind expression.

The matching part of the expression is `[0-9a-f]{2}` (i.e. two hex digits).

You need to add `i` or whatever flag uses the regex engine that you use to denote "ignore cases" (i.e. the `a-f` part of regex also match `A-F`). If you cannot (or do not want to) provide this flag you can put `[0-9A-Fa-f]` everywhere and it works.

If your regex engine does not support lookbehind you can get the same result using capturing groups:

```
00 00 00 [0-9a-f]{2} ([0-9a-f]{2})
```

Applied on the same input, this regex matches `00 00 00 20 f2` and its first (and only) capturing group matches `f2`.
Check it [online](https://regex101.com/r/B7NJu3/1).

#### Update

If it is important that the input string contains `78` somewhere after the matching part then add `(?=(?: [0-9a-z]{2})* 78)` to the first regex:

```
(?<=00 00 00 [0-9a-f]{2} )[0-9a-f]{2}(?=(?: [0-9a-z]{2})* 78)
```

`(?=` introduces a positive lookahead. It behaves similar to a lookbehind but must stay after the matching part of the reged and it is verified against the part of the string located after the matching part of the string.

`(?:` starts a non-capturing group.

The `[0-9a-z]{2}` followed or preceded by a space in the lookahead and lookbehind ensure that the entire matching string is composed only of 2 hex digit numbers separated by spaces. You can use `.*` instead but that will match anything, even if they do not follow the format of 2 hex digit numbers.

For the version without lookaheads or lookbehinds add `(?: [0-9a-z]{2})* 78` at the end of the regex:

```
00 00 00 [0-9a-f]{2} ([0-9a-f]{2})(?: [0-9a-z]{2})* 78
```

The regex matches the entire string starting with `00 00 00`  and ending with  `78` and the first capturing group matches the second number after `00 00 00`  (your target).

Comment: Looks mostly right, but I think the poster also wanted the string to end in `78`. (Just append `.*78` to it since your capture group already correctly returns `f2`)

Comment: @axiac that was beautiful. Exactly what I need, working like a charm. Thanks a lot, you all  !!

Answer (score 0):

Is the `f2` surrounded by asterisks?

Without asterisks:

```
00 00 00 [a-f0-9]+ (?<hexits>[a-f0-9]+).+78
```

With asterisks:

```
\*(?<hexits>[a-f0-9]+)\*
```

Comment: the output was similar to mine, it was: '00 00 00 20 f2 90 c2 91 c4 c4 ca 91 c0 c0 ca 91 94 cb c5 97 90 c5 90 c2 90 96 c7 ca 91 91 93 94 c6 c5 c6 cb c0 78' I need the second byte after the '00 00 00', Like, if it is '00 00 00 24 a1' I need the 'a1' byte. If it is '00 00 00 ff 2a' I need the '2a

Comment: then use the first format I supplied :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to match the hexadecimal value after "00 00 00": /00 00 00 ([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/. The value you want is in the capturing group, represented by \1.

Here is a demo:

```
import re

s = '70 75 62 71 00 7e 00 01 4c 00 06 72 61 6e 64 6f 6d 74 00 1c 4c 6a 2f 73 2f 6e 64 6f 6d 3b 78 70 77 25 00 00 00 20 f2 90 c2 91 c4 c4 ca 91 c0 c0 ca 91 94 cb c5 97 90 c5 90 c2 90 96 c7 ca 91 91 93 94 c6 c5 c6 cb c0 78'

match = re.search(r'00 00 00 ([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})', s)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

The output will be:

```
f2
```

Comment: I tried here and the output was '20'. I need the next byte. Like, if it is '00 00 00 24 a1' I need the 'a1' byte. If it is '00 00 00 ff 2a' I need the '2a'.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a regex for that.  Get the offset of 3 bytes of zero in a row and take the 4th one after it:

```py
s = '70 75 62 71 00 7e 00 01 4c 00 06 72 61 6e 64 6f 6d 74 00 1c 4c 6a 2f 73 2f 6e 64 6f 6d 3b 78 70 77 25 00 00 00 20 f2 90 c2 91 c4 c4 ca 91 c0 c0 ca 91 94 cb c5 97 90 c5 90 c2 90 96 c7 ca 91 91 93 94 c6 c5 c6 cb c0 78'
s2 = '01 02 03 00 00 00 05 06 07'

def locate(s):
    data = bytes.fromhex(s)
    offset = data.find(bytes([0,0,0]))
    return data[offset + 4]

print(f'{locate(s):02X}')
print(f'{locate(s2):02X}')
```

Output:

```
F2
06
```

You could also extract the "f2" string directly from the string:

```py
offset = s.index('00 00 00')
print(s[offset + 12 : offset + 14]) # 'f2'
```